# laravel my foreach only return me the last record in array

Tags: arrays, laravel, foreach

here is my code to store data into an array, but its not working, the page only show one element, which is the last element in the array. please help ty.

```
  $modProduct = array();
  if($product->product->subcategory->category->id==1){
    $modProduct[1] =  $product->product;
   }



  if($product->product->subcategory->category->id==4){
    $modProduct[4] =  $product->product;
   }


  if($product->product->subcategory->category->id==7){
    $modProduct[7] =  $product->product;
   }


  if($product->product->subcategory->category->id==10){
    $modProduct[10] =  $product->product;
   }


  if($product->product->subcategory->category->id==13){
    $modProduct[13] =  $product->product;
   }


  if($product->product->subcategory->category->id==16){
    $modProduct[16] =  $product->product;
   }
```

here is my output:

```
@foreach($modProduct as $index => $modProducts)
<div  ><a href="#tab-{{ $index }}" class="tab-nav" data-toggle="tab">
{{$modProducts->subcategory->category->name}}</a></div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: How many do you expect, 6? So are you sure the other if conditions are fulfilled?

Comment: my data in databse they have 6 category, that is why I do a if statement to validate them.

Comment: in your contoller return your value outsidee the foreach loop, beacouse it return you the last value

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this -

```
$modProduct = array();

foreach($product->product as $key => $value)
{
  $product_arr = array('1','4','7','10','13','16');

  if (in_array($value->subcategory->category->id, $product_arr))
  {
        modProduct[$value->subcategory->category->i] =  $value;
  }

}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: ty i will try it